# Gerrit Add Reviewers

Tags: gerrit

I have a project in Gerrit and each time I submit a change I manually have to add a group of reviewers to that change. Is there a mechanism that would allow me to specify reviewers that I want to be emailed for each change?

Answer (score 21):

You can use the [`%r=reviewer@mail.com` syntax](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-receive-pack.html) on your branch specifier during a push to automatically add reviewers to a change.

You can add as many emails as you want and all will be emailed, e.g.

```
git push tr:kernel/common HEAD:refs/for/experimental%r=a@a.com,r=b@b.com,cc=c@c.com
```

It’s a good idea to just [specify this in a remote block](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html#push_create) in your git config so you don't have to type all that each time.

Comment: [Here's script](https://github.com/sschuberth/dev-scripts/blob/master/gerrit/gerrit-push-for.sh) that uses this method, and it also suggests reviewers based on [git-contacts](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/contacts/git-contacts) if it's installed.

Comment: Does this work with Gerrit Groups as well ?

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to be using Gerrit with [Repo](https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html), then you can always specify reviewers while uploading changes.

```
repo upload --re=address_of_reviewer1,address_of_reviewer2...,address_of_reviewerN
```

Comment: Thats only if your project is Android :P

Comment: my project isn't Android, but it does happen to use both Gerrit and 'repo upload', so this was helpful to me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just type in the group name in the add reviewer box.  If this isn't working, what version of Gerrit are you using?

Comment: It is working but I want it to be automatic so the coders do not have to manually ad it each time there is a change because its always the same group of reviewers.

Comment: There is nothing built-in to Gerrit to handle this.  You need to use an external method - either a hook or a system watching the event stream (Jenkins)

Comment: There is a built-in way, it uses an augmented push branch syntax - see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658879/gerrit-add-reviewers/16823898#16823898

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gerrit hooks or use jenkins with the gerrit trigger to add the reviewers

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins for Gerrit which do exactly that:

- [Reviewers](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/admin/repos/plugins/reviewers)
- [Reviewers-by-blame](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/admin/repos/plugins%2Freviewers-by-blame)