# Add reviewers via the commit message

Tags: git, gerrit

Is it possible to add reviewers in Gerrit via a commit message? Consider this commit message:

```
component: make foo more bar

Foo was not bar enough, this change adds more bar to make foo fit better
in baz.

Change-Id: I4724e283214e0bfbb85a8e3d8db4971618e2609a
Cc: alice@example.com
Cc: bob@example.net
```

Here, `alice@example.com` and `bob@example.net` must be added as reviewers when pushing to gerrit.

I am aware of a [special branch specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16658879/427545) to add reviewers, but would like to have something more automated as I create commits. The changes are independent, though it would be nice if I could group them on a topic branch because they are related.

Comment: i think you can create a pre-push hook for this to create the special branch specifier from the commit msg

Comment: @jthill the git tag was added since commit hooks may also work here which requires git knowledge. I'll rollback if you don't mind?

Comment: I don't mind at all. I said my piece, you didn't even have to say yours, it's your post.  I could easily be wrong to think a large number of gerrit users here also know git well enough to answer, enough that bothering the much larger number of git-only users following that tag but don't know gerrit was not worth it.

Answer (score 11):

It is not possible to set per-commit reviewers, these are applied per push (see [gerrit's git-receive-pack manual](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-receive-pack.html)). Instead of executing `git push origin HEAD` or `git review` (assuming `origin` to be the gerrit remote, and `HEAD` the branch you want to push), you can run the following to add two reviewers for all new commits:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master%r=alice@example.com,r=bob@example.com
```

That gets applied to *all* commits which is not what you want. Due to the above limitations, let's change the workflow to push changes first and then set some reviewers.

---

Since Gerrit distinguishes between `Cc` (just send a mail notification) and reviewers (send a mail, but also mark the user as reviewer), I'll modify the commit message as follows:

```
component: make foo more bar

Foo was not bar enough, this change adds more bar to make foo fit better
in baz.

R=alice@example.com
R=bob@example.net

Change-Id: I4724e283214e0bfbb85a8e3d8db4971618e2609a
```

Given a number of commits, one can follow the following steps to add separate reviewers for each commit:

1. Gather a list of commits IDs (or `Change-Id`s). Example that assumes the master branch as base: `git rev-list --reverse origin/master..`
2. For each commit ID, scan for `R=...` (reviewers) in the commit message. The commit message for a given commit can be found with `git show --no-patch --format=%b COMMIT_ID`
3. If reviewers exist for a commit message, add them with the command `ssh -p 29418 user@host 'gerrit set-reviewers -a bob@example.net COMMIT_ID'` (instead of `COMMIT_ID`, you can also use the `Change-Id` which is `I4724e283214e0bfbb85a8e3d8db4971618e2609a` for the example).

To perform the above steps (together with auto-detecting the user, host and port settings), I wrote a Bash script: https://git.lekensteyn.nl/scripts/tree/git/gerrit-add-reviewers

It is recommended to have a `.gitreview` file in your repo with a remote that points to  a Gerrit instance. Then execute `~/scripts/gerrit-add-reviews origin/master..` from within that git repo to scan commit messages and add reviewers.

Answer (score 2):

I put together a script where you can pass the email addresses of the reviewers you want to add and it will take care of the rest for you. You can even fuzzy-find in existing committers (email and name), so that you don't have to type a lot.

https://gist.github.com/andersonvom/924fdc5f92aefa5eca9c

Just call it using:

```
$ greview [<rev1> [<rev2> [...]]]
```

Comment: That script uses a neat trick to set reviewers after push: `git push --receivepack="git-receive-pack --reviewer some@example.com --reviewer another@example.com" origin HEAD:refs/for/master/topic`

Answer (score 2):

Send a review for a change on the master branch to charlie@example.com:

```
git push ssh://review.example.com:29418/project HEAD:refs/for/master%r=charlie@example.com
```

Send reviews, but tagging them with the topic name 'bug42':

```
git push ssh://review.example.com:29418/project HEAD:refs/for/master%r=charlie@example.com,topic=bug42
```

Also CC two other parties:

```
git push ssh://review.example.com:29418/project HEAD:refs/for/master%r=charlie@example.com,cc=alice@example.com,cc=bob@example.com
```

Configure a push macro to perform the last action:

```
git config remote.charlie.url ssh://review.example.com:29418/project
git config remote.charlie.push HEAD:refs/for/master%r=charlie@example.com,cc=alice@example.com,cc=bob@example.com
```

afterwards .git/config contains the following:

```
[remote "charlie"]
  url = ssh://review.example.com:29418/project
  push = HEAD:refs/for/master%r=charlie@example.com,cc=alice@example.com,cc=bob@example.com
```

and now sending a new change for review to charlie, CC’ing both alice and bob is much easier:

```
git push charlie
```

Answer (score 1):

There is very nice [Git-review](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/git-review) tool for simplifying your life with Gerrit. Apart of other syntax sugar advantages, it allows you to add reviewers via command-line like:

```
git review --reviewers someone@someone.com someoneelse@someone.com
```

And of course you can create git aliases out of it to make it simpler like:

```
#git review --reviewers someone@someone.com someoneelse@someone.com
git publish
```

It's not directly answering your question "how to add reviewers from commit message", but it can be used, for example, to create custom pre-commit hook and extract emails first and push them to gerrit second

Answer (score 0):

Combine gerrit stream-events and set-reviewers, you can do this.

Actually, you first need get the CL's status (create, update & ...), then execute corresponding action, such as add reviewers, even submit CL.

1. get gerrit events from "[gerrit stream-events](https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/cmd-stream-events.html)" command.
2. parse the JSON format event as each line.
   In the JSON event, we can get project, branch, Change-Id, CL-number, subject of Commit(not entire commit), and a lot information.

if you really need entire commit message, "[gerrit query](https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/cmd-query.html)" is useful.

filter the "patchset-created", patchSet's number is 1(if you only like do this for new patchSet), parse the subject of commit, and get the reviewers as you predefined.

3. use "[gerrit set-reviewers](https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/cmd-set-reviewers.html)" command, to add reviewer.

as my practice, use python, all this is easy.

Its flow is like a tiny Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution works

ssh -p gerrit set-reviewers [--project (PROJECT) | -p (PROJECT)] [--add (REVIEWER) … | -a (REVIEWER) …] [--] {COMMIT | CHANGE-ID}

Example: ssh -p 29418 gerrit.example.com gerrit set-reviewers -a anuj@example.com Iac6b2ac2