# Add reviewers to gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit, git-review

I've read the Question ID:[Gerrit Add Reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658879/gerrit-add-reviewers)
However, my requirements are a little different.

I have not given my users "push" rights, hence *git push tr:kernel/common HEAD:refs/for/experimental%r=a@a.com,r=b@b.com,cc=c@c.com* will be redundant for me.

I am using git review -R, however, using this, even though the changes get uploaded, I am not able to add any specific reviewer using command line or some local config. Is there any work around?

Answer (score 2):

Gerrit's Push permission controls who can push to e.g. refs/heads/*, not general use of the `git push` command. The example for pushing to refs/for/experimental in your question should work just fine for you.

If you want to continue using the `git review` command (which oddly enough doesn't appear to support selection of reviewers) you always have the option of adding the reviewers after you've uploaded the change. Use the [set-reviewers SSH command](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-set-reviewers.html) or the [/changes/<id>/reviewers REST endpoint](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#add-reviewer).

Comment: I wish git review command had something of the sort git review -r abc.mail.com.

Comment: That shouldn't be a difficult change. Consider contributing that feature if it's important to you.